# How to show randomly mathematic sign in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I know how to show number random using this code below from 0 to 9.

```
number = arc4random() % 10;
```

but how about random for mathematic sign? I have +, -, x, / sign and i want to show it randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int number = arc4random() % 4;
NSString *string = @"+,-,x,/";
NSLog(@"sign = %@", [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","] 
objectAtIndex:number]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a random between 0 and 3, and for example 0 is +, 1 is -, 2 is / and 3 is *. With a regular if you can sort that out.